# Reading a line of integers into a two dimensional array

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream

I have an input file that contains the following line:

```
15​​ 14​ ​13​ ​12 ​11​ ​30​ ​29​ ​28​ ​27 ​26​ ​45​ ​44​ ​43​ ​42 ​41 ​60​ ​59​ ​58​ ​57​ ​56​ ​75​ ​74​ ​73 ​72​ ​71
```

25 integers. I'm trying to read the integers into a 5*5 array of integers:

```
void BingoCard::fill(istream& input)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
                input >> fields[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

The printing code looks as follows:

```
void BingoCard::display(ostream& out) const
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            out << setw(5) << fields[i][j];
        }
        out << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

However, when I print the nested array, only the first number `15` shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. There is nothing conceptually wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Could you add the printing code as well?

Comment: How are you printing it? That appears to be the key piece that's missing.

Comment: The code looks right but I suspect the value of `size` is not set correctly

Comment: Check your stream state after each read - for example your string of values in the post contains chars that failed to be read by the cin. After I removed them - the input was parsed successfully. String in hex looks like `31 35 E2 80 8B E2 80 8B 20 31 34 ...` instead of `31 35 20 31 34...`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I don't know what these words mean.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore What type is `fields` actually? Which words specifically confuse you?

Comment: fields is a nested array, int**. they are initialized via `new int*[5]` and `new int[5]`. "Checking the stream state" is what's confusing me.

Comment: What is required to happen if the value of `size*size` is not equal to the number of values represented in the input file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run this code, it works on my machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int ** fields = new int*[5];
    int size = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        fields[i] = new int[5];
    }

    ifstream fs("input.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            fs >> fields[i][j];
        }
    }


    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){ // this is display(ostream& out)
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            cout << setw(5) << fields[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the input file looks like,

```
$cat input.txt
15 14 13 12 11 30 29 28 27 26 45 44 43 42 41 60 59 58 57 56 75 74 73 72 71
$file input.txt
input.txt: ASCII text
```

Comment: That code runs on my machine as well. The problem is I'm reading from an ifstream, not cin. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Artemy Vysotsky was right, and I had bad data in my input file. I hand typed the data again, and now it works. Thanks for the help!